# Django form, change default max_length

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Within the model `"Example"` I have two fields:

```
-"description" (varchar, length 64).
-"description_length" integer.
```

`description_length` has different value for each record, and it is always between 1 and 64.

In a Django form how is possible set the `maxlength` description equal to the `description_length` variable value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing.

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Example

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['description'].max_length = self.instance.description_length
```

Just be sure your `description` model field is big enough to accomodate the text of `description_length`:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    MAX_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH = 1024

    description = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH)
    description_length = models.IntegerField(
        validators=MaxValueValidator(MAX_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH))
```